# Advance master branch after 3-way merge

Tags: git

Suppose my commits look like this:
[image]
Now, to perform a 3-way merge, I issue:

```
git checkout iss53
git merge master
```

Assuming there are no conflicts, my log now looks like this:
[image]
How do I advance `master` to C6?

The diagrams are adapted from those in [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/).

Comment: Side-question: May I ask how you created that illustration?

Comment: Those are nice diagrams! I'd put `C6` on the bottom row though, or on a middle row between the two, for a "before advancing master label" style illustration.

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen and torek: I'm afraid I did not create the diagrams from scratch - they are Photoshopped versions of those from [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/). I simply moved the boxes and arrows as needed. I've edited my post to include the citation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git merge iss53
```

will do it by doing a fast forward.

Comment: Note that you must allow Git to do this "fast forward", but this *is* the default (so this is the easy and right answer here). Perhaps I should phrase this as "you must not *prevent* `git merge` from doing the fast forward"...

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the normal way you would deal with this.  Normally, you would just merge `iss53` back into `master`.  This would typically be done by pushing `iss53` after its merge with `master`, and then creating a pull request.  Then, `iss53` would be merged into `master` and the two branches would at that exact moment be functionally equivalent.

The literal answer to your question can be gotten using `git branch -f`:

```
git branch -f master C5
```

and replace `C5` with the SHA-1 hash of the commit to which the HEAD of `iss53` is pointing.  But again, I would not do this normally.

Another approach here would be to *rebase* `iss53` on `master`, and then fast-forward `master` using the rebased branch:

```
master: C0 -- C1 -- C2 -- C4
                     \
iss53:                C3 -- C5
```

Checkout `iss53`, rebase on `master`:

```
git checkout iss53
git rebase master
```

After this, the diagrams look like this:

```
master: C0 -- C1 -- C2 -- C4
                           \
iss53:                      C3' -- C5'
```

Now you can just push `iss53` into `master` and fast-forward this latter branch.  This would leave `master` looking like this:

```
master: C0 -- C1 -- C2 -- C4 -- C3' -- C5'
```